# Changing Background Color of UWP Template 10 Modal

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

I have created Login Modal which shows on Application Start.

I want to show total **white** Login Screen so I have changed ModalBackground Color and Opacity as follows.

Following Code that I have written in App.xaml.cs:

```
public override async Task OnStartAsync(StartKind startKind, IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            // long-running startup tasks go here
            // await Task.Delay(5000);
            WindowWrapper.Current().Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
            {

                var modal = Window.Current.Content as ModalDialog;
                modal.ModalContent = new Views.Login();
                modal.IsModal = true;
                 modal.ModalBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                 modal.Opacity = 100;
            });

            NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.MainPage));
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

But the thing is that it has also changed properties of Busy Modal and Busy Modal also started looking white.

How to change background color of just Login Modal?

Answer (score 0):

change the background color of your Login view control